Laravel: Class error 'STS\ZipStream\Facades\Zip' not found when zipstream
Implementing the zipstream in our application but it gives me an error when zipping the exported data.
So far this what I have done

composer require stechstudio/laravel-zipstream
Copy & paste the example provided
When I tried to export, it gives me an error "Class 'STS\ZipStream\Facades\Zip' not found"
Check my config/app.php, manually added the STS\ZipStream\ZipStreamServiceProvider::class

Im following the instructions here https://github.com/stechstudio/laravel-zipstream?tab=readme-ov-file
Versions

Using version ^4.14 for stechstudio/laravel-zipstream
Laravel Framework 6.20.44
php version 7.4.9

Controller
use STS\ZipStream\Facades\Zip;

$zip = Zip::create('my_files.zip');
$zip->addFile('file1.txt', 'contents of file1');
$zip->addFileFromPath('path/to/file2.pdf', 'file2.pdf');

return response()->stream(function () use ($zip) {
    $zip->finish();
}, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="my_files.zip"',
]);

Tried the ff but still not working

Check the composer.json, the packaged has been installed
execute the ff commands: php artisan config:clear & php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload

How do I fix the error "Class 'STS\ZipStream\Facades\Zip' not found"?"

im new to this but sometimes
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
helped me.
and make sure you have this line in your composer.json
"require": {
"stechstudio/laravel-zipstream": "^4.14"
}
then use: composer dump-autoload

I also did that

The use STS\ZipStream\Facades\Zip; facade is described as a breaking change in version ^5 of laravel-zipstream (See the release notes here).
You're using version ^4 so you need to access the facade a different way...
// use STS\ZipStream\Facades\Zip;
// becomes:
use STS\ZipStream\ZipStreamFacade;

// Zip::create(...);
// becomes:
ZipStreamFacade::create(...);

